# Open multiple copies of same file in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a script file called CreateClientDatabase.SQL, double clicking it opens it in SSMS where we can change a few parameters and execute it.

Problem:
A few hours/days later we may need to do the same again for another client, but if the original tab in SSMS has not been closed then double clicking the file will simply bring that tab to the fore and not actually open the file.
So it's easy to assume the script you are now looking at is the same as the file when it is not, and this can lead to all sorts of issues.

Is there a way round this? 
Can SSMS open a second copy of the file, or warn the user that it hasn't actually opened it much like Excel does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147063/opening-a-stored-procedure-file-multiple-times-in-sql-server-management-studio), but the question is on DBA Stackexchange?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer  That link refers to stored objects and the question refers to `.sql` files saved on disk.

Answer (score 1):

What you need, I think, is something similar to **excel** or **word template files**: whenever you open such file by double-click, a new document with the contents of the template is created.

**SSMSBoost add-in** (that I develop) has “**Autoreplacements**” feature: you can define a “magic token”, that will be replaced by your script, whenever that token is typed. For example, we have pre-defined token “sel”, which is replaced by “select * from” whenever you type “sel” and press space.
You could associate your script with any word, like “doit”, so whenever you visit next customer, you just open new query window, type that word+space and you have your script in the window immediately.

Just to mention: SSMSBoost allows you to define “favorite” connections, so, you can save all your cutomer’s servers in one list and quickly switch between them.

**Alternative:**
Have a look at **SSMS Templates (View->Template explorer)**. SSMS allows creating your own templates and opening them by double-clicking their name from Template Explorer. In connection with **SSMSBoost “Preferred connections”** list you have a good setup to start your work quickly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If file is opened from the windows explorer then it opens another instance of SSMS.

Comment: This depends on your SSMS version and user settings.  On my machine queries that are double clicked on all open within the same SSMS window as new tabs.

Comment: Agree with @iamdave, this does not happen for me.  What version of SSMS are you using  ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.15600.2

Comment: What you can do is open a second instance of SSMS from the task bar, then within that instance you can go to File > Recent Files and open up the same file you have open in the first instance. SSMS will warn you to reload if changes are saved in the other window (whether it was the first or second instance open).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to d*etect when the SQL script file is changed outside if the SSMS environment*:

make sure that Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents -> `Detect when file is changed outside the environment` is checked.

More details can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/09/14/detect-when-a-file-is-changed-outside-the-environment/).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will work for my case.  The file is not changed outside the environment, the problem is that the script is changed within the environment but not saved or closed.  Reopening the file does not reload it